# Susy2: how do I get or set my margins

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass

I have a gist here:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/09f8182351b9cba3af21

What am I doing wrong or not doing - I'd imagine if I used the span mixin that the margins would be calculated as well, but they're all 0 on the li items. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using:

```
gutter-position: split
```

adds the margins back in.

gutter position in the susy docs:

http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#gutter-position

Comment: The span mixin does calculate gutters (based on the `gutters` setting) - and `gutter-position` only effects *where* those gutters are applied. I'm not sure I understand the original problem. Removing `gutter-position` from your demo reverts to the default `after` setting, with gutters applied to the right margin.

Comment: Just struggling a bit with the new syntax and possibilities in Susy2 - spent most of yesterday toying around with it and had a few lightbulb moments. It's a great version - thanks Eric :)